# OOM with ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()

Tags: java

I wanted to decompress the `byte[]` which is already compressed with `Deflater`(Since my file zipped), but while decompress using `inflater`, am trying to get byte array using `outputStream.toByteArray()` which in turn throws `OOM`, Kindly suggest some solutions to avoid `OOM`.

```
public static byte[] decompress(byte[] data){
    Inflater inflater = new Inflater();   
       inflater.setInput(data);  
       ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);  
       byte[] buffer = new byte[data.length+100];  
       while (!inflater.finished()) {  
        int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);  
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);  
       }  
       outputStream.close();  
       byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Note: Am aware about the internal implementation of `toByteArray()`, but not getting any alternative for that.

Comment: Solution to avoid OOM: Add more memory to the JVM.

Comment: The first question here is why are you using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` at all? Can't the downstream code work with an `InputStream`?

Answer (score 2):

What is your overall goal?

If you HAVE to decompress the whole thing in memory (can't change the return value and parameter of the "decompress" method), then indeed you have to add more memory.

But if you are required - for example - to decompress a file, then with proper stream usage your program should be able to decompress arbitrarily large files with very little memory (read a little from the compressed file, decompress, write result to output file, repeat it...).

[Compressing and decompressing large size data in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955049/compressing-and-decompressing-large-size-data-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you HAVE to decompress in memory, and you have just enough memory for the compressed input and inflated output, but not much more, then you should consider that ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray() creates a new byte array, effectively doubling the memory needed (until the byteArrayOutputStream is garbage collected).

So, I think that the following is possible, and reduces memory consumption for the price of more CPU usage:

1. inflate the input via streaming, and remember the exact size of the inflated data (suppose it's 999999999).
2. create a subclass of ByteArrayOutputStream in order to access it's internal buffer.
3. create an instance of the subclass, with the exact size of the inflated data ( MyByteArrayOutputStream(999999999) ), and pass it to the inflater.
4. after inflater finished, return the internal buffer, which by that time holds the inflated data.

Since the subclass creates it's internal buffer with the right size at the beginning, it won't copy it during deflation. Also, because the internal buffer has just the right size, you can safely pass it to the caller without copying. In this way your memory need is only the input + output byte array sizes plus some overhead (but NOT input + 2*output).

Comment: Could you point me to some regulation about this? I checked meta and found that if the two answers are two different solutions (not edited versions for example) then they should be judged on their own merit. I think you should downvote it if it's low quality etc.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269545/two-solutions-one-or-two-answers : "If they are two completely separate things that have nothing to do with one another, it would probably be best to post them as separate answers. Not only is that somewhat less confusing, but more importantly, it allows the community to vote on them independently. This provides a more accurate judgment of their merits."